# Inverse Fourier formula for lattice random variables

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Suppose that $X$ has a lattice distribution such that no strict sublattice of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ contains $X$ with probability $1$. Define the characteristic function of $X$ as usual:
$$
\gamma(t)\equiv E\exp(it'X)=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}^d}\exp(it'x)\Pr(X=x).
$$
My book is giving the following as the inversion formula for $\Pr(X=x)$:
$$
\Pr(X=x)=(2\pi)^{-d}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^d}\exp(-it'x)\gamma(t)dt.
$$
Why is $t$ restricted to $[-\pi,\pi]^d$ please?

Comment: Because otherwise the integral would diverge.

Comment: @Did can you clarify? It's not clear to me so that's why I asked the question.

Comment: To downvoter: can you please explain?

Comment: And because, for every integers $x$ and $y$, $$(2\pi)^{-d}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^d}\exp(-it'x)\exp(it'y)dt
$$ is $0$ for every $y\ne x$ and $1$ for $y=x$.

Comment: "no strict sublattice of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ contains $X$ with probability $1$" This is not needed.

Comment: @Did I copied that bit from the text. I'm thinking about your other comments. Thanks for them.

Comment: @Did Hello, I am very interested, what is the name of the book you have read？ Is it convenient to help me?